# How to store the number of time each key pressed in android?

Tags: android

Sorry for asking this type of a question. I'm a newbee to android and i have this idea to develop an app to detect stress based on dwell time and flight time of the keys. Is there a way to get these values through a background service ? I'm aware about creating an intent service and using alarmManager to run this service only during a certain time of the day. but the core part is missing as to get dwell time and flight time of keys pressed in the keyboard.

Comment: As far as the system goes, you cannot/should not intercept events outside of your application context. That being said, what you described looks a LOT like a keylogger, and your question is likely to be closed

Comment: You could create your own soft keyboard implementation.  Though you'd need to get users to make it the default one to get the information.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get these values through a background service ?

No.

> get dwell time and flight time of keys pressed in the keyboard

Write your own input method editor. Then, convince users to use it.

Bear in mind that many existing input method editors actually use long-press events for different keys (e.g., long-press U to get 7 without having to switch to a separate set of keys). Other input method editors use gestures, where the finger does not leave the keyboard. In other words, the concepts of dwell time and flight time — originally developed for physical keyboards — would have to be revisited for soft keyboards anyway.